# Get Specific Data form request.post response in Python

Tags: python, api, request, sendgrid

I am using sendgrid api to send email to users and then check the status,

```
res = requests.post(url)
print type(res)
```

and it prints type as `<class 'requests.models.Response'>`

on the Postman API client I am getting this:

```js
{
"message": "error",
"errors": [
"JSON in x-smtpapi could not be parsed"
]
}
```

I want to fetch only the `message` value from response. I have written the following piece of code but doesn't work:

```
for keys in res.json():
    print str(res[keys]['message'])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to loop; just access the `'message'` key on the dictionary returned by the `response.json()` method:

```
print res.json()['message']
```

It may be easier to follow what is going on by storing the result of the `response.json()` call in a separate variable:

```
json_result = res.json()
print json_result['message']
```

The reason Postman API returns an error message is because your POST didn't actually contain any data; you probably want to send some JSON to the API:

```
data = some_python_structure
res = requests.post(url, json=data)
```

When you use the `json` argument, the `requests` library will encode it to JSON for you, and set the correct content type header.